# Pandas 'isin' : Retrieving rows except a list of column indexes

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I want to retrieve rows which are not the indexes of a list of columns.

Below is a df :
[image] 
 I'm trying to extract rows of 'text' columns which are not state, gender. I tried the below to retrieve rows except the indexes of 'state' column. But how do I do it for multiple columns?

```
df_2 = df[~df.index.isin(state.index)]

# multiple columns - doesn't work
df_2 = df[~df.index.isin(state.index,gender.index)]
```

Comment: `I'm trying to extract rows of 'text' columns which are not state, gender.` Please explain this again, more clearly, and with an example. I also want to see your expected output, if you'd so please.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The rows where 'STATE' and 'GENDER' have '0' in both of them. Then only those 'TEXT' rows should be extracted.

Comment: `df.query("STATE == 0 and GENDER == 0").TEXT`